# HTTP POST method returns 500 error using swift for azure web api server

Tags: ios, asp.net, swift, asp.net-web-api, xmlhttprequest

I am new to iOS development.
GET method working fine.

[GET](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FknFn.png)

However, POST method returns 500 response..

[POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqSaF.png)

Here is my POST controller is Swift:

```
@IBAction func pressedPost(_ sender: Any) {
    let restEndPoinst: String = "http://tresmorewebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/accounts"
    guard let url = URL(string: restEndPoinst) else {
        print("Error creating URL")
        return
    }

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // api key need urlRequest.setValue(<#T##value: String?##String?#>, forHTTPHeaderField: "APIKey")


    let jsonDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    jsonDictionary.setValue(9, forKey: "Id")
    jsonDictionary.setValue("From iOS!", forKey: "UserName")
    jsonDictionary.setValue("HAHAH iOS", forKey: "UserEmail")
    jsonDictionary.setValue(200.44, forKey: "Rebate")
    jsonDictionary.setValue(1200.20, forKey: "MemCom")

    let jsonData: Data
    do{
        jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDictionary, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
    }
    catch{
        print("Error creating JSON")
        return
    }

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler:
        {
            (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            print("Error:")
            print(error)
            print("response:")
            print(response)
            print("Data:")
            print(String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))
    })

    task.resume()
}
```

And my model is look like below:

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public decimal Rebate { get; set; }
    public decimal MemCom { get; set; }
}
```

I followed Youtube tutorial using swift and azure by asp.net web api
if you search `iOS Swift Calling POST, PUT and DELETE on Azure REST Web Service` that is the one I was following.

Please help me how to fix POST request to insert some data to my azure web server.

Comment: By definition, a 500 HTTP status code is an internal server error. If there was a problem with your request (for example, a malformed payload), you should have received a 4xx status code, e.g. 400, or 403. This seems like a problem with the server.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook However, If I use Postman http debugging program, I can do POST and it works perfectly! But I don't know why iOS gives 500 error

Comment: Actually, is it possible that you're forgetting to assign the `httpBody` property of your URLRequest after serializing the JSON data?

Comment: @daltonclaybrook Oh Shoot.. That is correct it fixed!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answer to this question..
I forgot httpbody

Here is fixed POST in do-catch:

```
do{
        jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonDictionary, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
        urlRequest.httpBody = jsonData
    }
```